# Matching an exact word from a string

Tags: javascript, csv

I need a way to match a word against a string and not get false positives.  Let me give an example of what I mean:

- "/thing" should match the string "/a/thing"
- "/thing" should match the string "/a/thing/that/is/here"
- "/thing" should **NOT** match the string "/a/thing_foo"

Basically, it should match if the exact characters are there in the first string and the second, but not if there are run-ons in the second (such as an underscore like in `thing_foo`).

Right now, I'm doing this, which is not working.

`let found = b.includes(a);  // true`

Hopefully my question is clear enough.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you considered regex?  the following pattern should work: `/\/thing\b/`

Comment: There's not really enough information here. Why does a string with a prefix pass and the string with a suffix fail? Would `/a/thing/foo` pass? What about `/thing-foo`, `/thing~foo`, etc?

Comment: @Phil sorry, let me elaborate a bit.

Comment: @Phil I've added some more information.  Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: @jewnbug97 what other characters besides `_` and `/` should delimit the potential match? For example, what about hyphens and tilde, ie `-` and `~`?

Comment: @Phil it should only be an underscore

Comment: @Phil I'm tapping out, this is all yours. :)

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm asking. If you're searching for `/thing` and the string is `"/a/thing/that-is/here"`, should that pass or fail?

Comment: @Phil There will only ever be an underscore, so in your example it would be `/a/thing/that_is/here` (which should return true because `/thing` still matches)

Comment: It doesn't conflict.  `/thing` should match a string `/thing`.  `/thing` should NOT match `/thing_word` (if it is concatenated to a word with an underscore).

Comment: Sorry, I got my example wrong. I meant `/a/thing-that/is/here`

Comment: @Phil yes, i dont have to worry about hyphens, it will only have underscores

Comment: Then see the first comment on this question from @TheIncorrigible1. You should also clarify your question. The statement _"not if there are run-ons in the second **such as** an underscore"_ makes this ambiguous

Comment: @Phil I'll update that comment.  Also, how would I use that regex with a variable?  I'm doing `let filter = new RegExp(a + '\b')` but it's not matching properly.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boy did this turn in to a classic [*XY Problem*](http://xyproblem.info/).

If I had to guess, you want to know if a path contains a particular segment.

In that case, split the string on a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for `'/'` and use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const paths = ["/a/thing", "/a/thing/that/is/here", "/a/thing_foo"]
const search = '/thing'

paths.forEach(path => {
  const segments = path.split(/(?=\/)/)
  console.log('segments', segments)
  console.info(path, ':', segments.includes(search))
})
```

Using the positive lookahead expression `/(?=\/)/` allows us to split the string on `/` whilst maintaining the `/` prefix in each segment.

---

Alternatively, if you're still super keen in using a straight regex solution, you'll want something like this

```js
const paths = ["/a/thing", "/a/thing/that/is/here", "/a/thing_foo", "/a/thing-that/is/here"]
const search = '/thing'

const rx = new RegExp(search + '\\b') // note the escaped backslash

paths.forEach(path => {
  console.info(path, ':', rx.test(path))
})
```

Note that this will return false positives if the search string is followed by a hyphen or tilde as those are considered to be word boundaries. You would need a more complex pattern and I think the first solution handles these cases better.

Comment: This is the route I initially was going to take, but the strings I get have a hard coded `/` in front of them that I need to match on.  In your example, the search variable has no `/` so it's easier to match against a split'd string.   I could manually re-add the `/` back to it, but this is happening in a loop with potentially many strings, so I'm thinking the regex option is the best.  I'm just not sure how to match against a regex when it's in variable form.

Comment: @jewnbug97 I've updated my answer to include the require prefix

Comment: @jewnbug97 I've also added a plain regex solution but I think it's sub-optimal

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using regular expressions...

**e.g.** The following regular expression `/\/thing$/` - matches anything that ends with `/thing`.

```js
console.log(/\/thing$/.test('/a/thing')) // true
console.log(/\/thing$/.test('/a/thing_foo')) // false
```

**Update: To use a variable...**

```js
var search = '/thing'
console.log(new RegExp(search + '$').test('/a/thing')) // true
console.log(new RegExp(search + '$').test('/a/thing_foo')) // false
```

Comment: Given OP's attempt at using `String.prototype.include`, I'd say it's unlikely the required string always occurs at the end

Comment: @Phil, we don't have any examples of sample data sets, or delimiters for that matter... so I'm just going with what was presented. Happy to update if more examples are provided.

Comment: @NickGrealy actually, I think this is exactly what I need.  The only thing different is that `thing` in my case is in a variable, lets say `a`.  How could I do something like `a.test('/path')` using your regex?

Comment: It's cool, I just suspect this won't be the final answer. **_"Delimiters"_**, as you mention, is exactly what OP needs to define

Comment: @jewnbug97 wait, so you're saying the string you're searching for **has to** appear at the end of the searchable string? If so, see [String.prototype.endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

Comment: @NickGrealy sorry for the wild goose chase... I updated my question to hopefully clarify my needs.  The string will not always necessarily be at the end.

Comment: I concur with @Phil

Answer (score 0):

Simply with following regex you can do it

```
var a = "/a/thing";
var b = "/a/thing/that/is/here";
var c = "/a/thing_foo";
var pattern = new RegExp(/(:?(thing)(([^_])|$))/);
pattern.test(a) // true
pattern.test(b) // true
pattern.test(c)  // false
```